# Adding an eventListener to multiple elements while utilizing an attribute from a child element

Tags: javascript, responsive-design, addeventlistener, dom-events

In my HTML I have this tag hierarchy repeated a bunch:

```
<figure>
    <div class="proj-photo">
        <img>
        <div></div>
        <a></a>
    </div>
    <figcaption></figcaption>
</figure>
```

When I am on a non-touch screen I have a hover effect which displays the **a** tag as a button to launch a link.

On a touch screen I want to add an eventListener to the entire figure which launches the href of its embedded **a** tag when its pressed.

This is what I've written, but it doesn't work:

```
const isTouchScreen = window.matchMedia( "(hover: none)" )

if (isTouchScreen.matches){
    console.log("Touch screen in use")
    const figures = document.querySelectorAll("figure")
    const projLinks = document.querySelectorAll("figure > div > a")
    var i = 0
    function clickHandler(i){
      window.open(projLinks[i], '_blank')
    }

    function assignListeners(i){
        figures[i].addEventListener('click', clickHandler(i))
    }

    for (i in figures) {
        assignListeners(i)
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you can either wrap your div inside you `<a>` tag or completely replace the `div` with the `<a>` tag and use it as a div. It will make the operation more simple to do.

Comment: Replace `figures[i].addEventListener('click', clickHandler(i))` with `figures[i].addEventListener('click', clickHandler)`. `clickHandler(i)` is `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things that needs to be fixed in your code:

- Your loop pass the element, not its index, so it needs to look like this

  ```
  for( var i = 0; i < figures.length; i++) {
     assignListeners(i)
  }
  ```
- To have access to its position index you could store it in a custom attribute. *Note, I also removed the `(i)` from `clickHandler`, or else it will fire when add the handler.*

  ```
  function assignListeners(i){
    figures[i].setAttribute('data-id', i);
    figures[i].addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
  }
  ```
- Then when clicked at, you can use the custom attribute to do something with

  ```
  function clickHandler(e){
    alert(this.dataset.id)
  }
  ```

---

Stack snippet *(disabled the touch detection for this sample to work)*

```js
//const isTouchScreen = window.matchMedia( "(hover: none)" )

//if (isTouchScreen.matches){
    //console.log("Touch screen in use")
    const figures = document.querySelectorAll("figure")
    const projLinks = document.querySelectorAll("figure > div > a")
    var i = 0
    function clickHandler(e){
      alert(this.dataset.id)
    }

    function assignListeners(i){
        figures[i].setAttribute('data-id', i);
        figures[i].addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
    }

    for( var i = 0; i < figures.length; i++) {
        assignListeners(i)
    }
//}
```

```html
<figure>
    <div class="proj-photo">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100">
        <div></div>
        <a href="#">Link</a>
    </div>
    <figcaption></figcaption>
</figure>
<figure>
    <div class="proj-photo">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100">
        <div></div>
        <a href="#">Link</a>
    </div>
    <figcaption></figcaption>
</figure>
```